# gofabric8 installation issue

Tags: minikube, fabric8

When I am trying to install **fabric8** through `gofabric8` start command.
I am getting below error

> Node "minikube" is invalid: []: Forbidden: node updates may only change labels, taints, or capacity (or configSource, if the DynamicKubeletConfig feature gate is enabled)

It is trying to install configmapcontroller and when I checked logs I am getting below result

> Failed to list *api.ConfigMap: configmaps is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:default:configmapcontroller" cannot list resource "configmaps" in API group "" at the cluster scope

Answer (score 2):

Check if your `configmapcontroller` serviceaccount in `default` namespaces has sufficient rights to do `list`. I assume you will have `NO` reply.

```
kubectl auth can-i get list --as=system:serviceaccount:default:configmapcontroller
kubectl auth can-i get * --as=system:serviceaccount:default:configmapcontroller
```

In order to fix: create clusterrolebinding and grant `cluster-admin` role to `configmapcontroller` serviceaccount

```
kubectl create clusterrolebinding configmapcontroller-clusterrole-binding --clusterrole=cluster-admin --serviceaccount=default:configmapcontroller
```

Next check you will have

```
root@mini-2:~# kubectl auth can-i get list --as=system:serviceaccount:default:configmapcontroller
yes
```

After that remove configmapcontroller pod and it will be successfully recreated.

--

I had the same issue with `exposecontroller`:

> F0726 12:57:01.499537       1 exposecontroller.go:66] failed to create
>   new strategy: failed to create node port expose strategy: failed to
>   list nodes: nodes is forbidden: User
>   "system:serviceaccount:default:exposecontroller" cannot list resource
>   "nodes" in API group "" at the cluster scope

and fixed with

```
kubectl create clusterrolebinding add-on-cluster-admin1 --clusterrole=cluster-admin --serviceaccount=default:exposecontroller
```

BTW: I was unable to install successfully latest gofabric8 version, so I used [0.4.136](https://github.com/fabric8io/gofabric8/releases/tag/v0.4.136). More info can be found here: [gofabric8 fails to install service account, console, jenkins](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/fabric8/rUOGSGA8Wjg)

My result: Everything was installed successfully, able to reach gogs,jenkins,nexus apps

```
root@mini-2:~# kubectl get all -n default
NAME                                           READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
pod/configmapcontroller-795cc65b5f-x7ghx       1/1     Running   0          64m
pod/exposecontroller-54f797dc98-9fhsq          1/1     Running   0          6m15s
pod/fabric8-6478468fc6-xnt5m                   2/2     Running   0          6m20s
pod/fabric8-docker-registry-694b47bbbf-fms5r   1/1     Running   0          64m
pod/fabric8-forge-f96b59845-7vpg6              1/1     Running   0          64m
pod/gogs-5f765f4d56-msj2w                      1/1     Running   0          6m24s
pod/jenkins-647564f86f-bgvc8                   1/1     Running   0          64m
pod/nexus-6997d66d8d-97kfk                     1/1     Running   0          64m


NAME                              TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)           AGE
service/fabric8                   NodePort    10.98.94.35     <none>        80:31537/TCP      65m
service/fabric8-docker-registry   NodePort    10.102.17.73    <none>        80:30103/TCP      65m
service/fabric8-forge             NodePort    10.96.176.103   <none>        80:30372/TCP      65m
service/gogs                      NodePort    10.104.189.85   <none>        80:32235/TCP      65m
service/gogs-ssh                  NodePort    10.96.23.147    <none>        22:30215/TCP      65m
service/jenkins                   NodePort    10.111.7.181    <none>        80:32746/TCP      65m
service/jenkins-jnlp              NodePort    10.96.214.184   <none>        50000:32480/TCP   65m
service/jenkinshift               NodePort    10.105.19.36    <none>        80:30604/TCP      65m
service/kubernetes                ClusterIP   10.96.0.1       <none>        443/TCP           77m
service/nexus                     NodePort    10.97.42.228    <none>        80:30277/TCP      64m


NAME                                      READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/configmapcontroller       1/1     1            1           64m
deployment.apps/exposecontroller          1/1     1            1           64m
deployment.apps/fabric8                   1/1     1            1           64m
deployment.apps/fabric8-docker-registry   1/1     1            1           64m
deployment.apps/fabric8-forge             1/1     1            1           64m
deployment.apps/gogs                      1/1     1            1           64m
deployment.apps/jenkins                   1/1     1            1           64m
deployment.apps/nexus                     1/1     1            1           64m

NAME                                                 DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
replicaset.apps/configmapcontroller-795cc65b5f       1         1         1       64m
replicaset.apps/exposecontroller-54f797dc98          1         1         1       6m15s
replicaset.apps/exposecontroller-86c8f4d49b          0         0         0       64m
replicaset.apps/fabric8-6478468fc6                   1         1         1       6m20s
replicaset.apps/fabric8-cfd8758b7                    0         0         0       64m
replicaset.apps/fabric8-docker-registry-694b47bbbf   1         1         1       64m
replicaset.apps/fabric8-forge-f96b59845              1         1         1       64m
replicaset.apps/gogs-5f765f4d56                      1         1         1       6m24s
replicaset.apps/gogs-7fdf88d6d7                      0         0         0       64m
replicaset.apps/jenkins-647564f86f                   1         1         1       64m
replicaset.apps/nexus-6997d66d8d                     1         1         1       64m
```

Comment: can you please help on the below issue?

Comment: @SiddharthKaushal: as I mention on another thread, please ask a new question. You have received excellent help here already, so please offer feedback to VKR (did it help in your case?) and vote/accept if you can.